# unable to verify the first certificate ionic 4

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins

I tried to install Browser Tab plugin on my application:
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-browsertab`
and the output was this:

```
    > ionic integrations enable cordova
    [INFO] Downloading integration cordova
    Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)
```

I tried to use 
`npm config set strict-ssl false`
but the error continues

Comment: are you using any proxies by any chance?

Comment: In school yes but when I'm in home I don't use one and the error continues